# springfox swagger Json errors

Tags: swagger-2.0, springfox

I am new to swagger.
I have the folowing code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = { V1P})
@Api(value = V1P, description= "My Operations Management API")
public class MethodController {


    /**
     * @return -
     */
    @ApiOperation(value = "retrieve task information", notes = "retrieve service instance information", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @SuppressWarnings("nls")
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH , method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> retrieve() {
        ....
    }

    @ApiOperation(nickname = "openTaskUsingGet", value = "Open a task", notes = "API to Open a task", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "taskReferenceId", value = "Reference ID of the task", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "taskSummary", value = "The task's summary description", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "contentDocumentId", value = "The content document ID of the  task", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "createdBy", value = "The name of the creating user", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "teamReferenceId", value = "The creating team reference ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "taskFromTime", value = "Task planned start time", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "taskDueTime", value = "Task planned due time", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "taskGroup", value = "Task group name", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "taskType", value = "Task type", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteLongitude", value = "Site longitude coordinate", required = true, dataType = "double", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteLatitude", value = "Site latitude coordinate", required = true, dataType = "double", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteZipCode", value = "Site zip code", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteName", value = "Site name", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteCountry", value = "Site country", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteState", value = "Site state", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteCity", value = "Site city", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteAddress", value = "Site address", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteComments", value = "Site comments", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "siteReferenceId", value = "Site reference ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "eqType", value = "Equipment type", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "eqReferenceId", value = "Equipment reference ID", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query")
      })
    @SuppressWarnings({ "nls", "javadoc" })
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/mob/openTask" , method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> openTask(
            @RequestParam("taskReferenceId")                String taskReferenceId,
            @RequestParam("taskSummary")                    String taskSummary,
            @RequestParam("contentDocumentId")          String contentDocumentId,
            @RequestParam("createdBy")                  String createdBy,
            @RequestParam("teamReferenceId")                String teamReferenceId,
            @RequestParam("taskFromTime")                   String taskFromTime,
            @RequestParam("taskDueTime")                    String taskDueTime,
            @RequestParam("taskGroup")                  String taskGroup,
            @RequestParam("taskType")                       String taskType,
            @RequestParam("siteLongitude")              double siteLongitude,
            @RequestParam("siteLatitude")                   double siteLatitude,
            @RequestParam("siteZipCode")                    String siteZipCode,
            @RequestParam("siteName")                       String siteName,
            @RequestParam("siteCountry")                    String siteCountry,
            @RequestParam("siteState")                  String siteState,
            @RequestParam("siteCity")                       String siteCity,
            @RequestParam("siteAddress")                    String siteAddress,
            @RequestParam("siteComments")                   String siteComments,
            @RequestParam("siteReferenceId")                String siteReferenceId,
            @RequestParam("eqType")                     String eqType,
            @RequestParam("eqReferenceId")              String eqReferenceId){
            ....
    }

    @ApiOperation(nickname = "openTaskUsingPOST", value = "Open a task", notes = "API to Open a task", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @SuppressWarnings({ "nls", "javadoc" })
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/mob/openTask" , method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> openTask(@RequestBody OpenTaskCmd cmd){
        ...
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get an HTML summary of a package content", notes = "API to get an HTML summary of a package content", response = String.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "packageName", value = "The name of the required package", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "packageVersion", value = "The required package version", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query")
    })
    @SuppressWarnings({ "nls", "javadoc" })
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/mob/getContent" , method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> getContent(@RequestParam("packageName") String pkgName,
                               @RequestParam("packageVersion") String pkgVersion){
        ....
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get the activities of a project as a Json array", notes = "API to get the activities of a project as a Json array")
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
    @ApiImplicitParams({
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "startIndex", value = "The first activity index", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "pageSize", value = "The number of activities", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query")
    })
    @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_PATH + "/mob/readActivities" , method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> readActivities(@RequestParam("startIndex") int startIndex,
                                   @RequestParam("pageSize") int pageSize){
        ...
    }
}
```

ths is part of the json I get:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"description":"Operation Management","version":"v1","title":"API","host":"127.0.0.1","basePath":"/","tags":[{"name":"v1","description":"Operations Management API"}],
"paths":{
"/v1/proxy/resource":{..."responses":{"200":{"description":"Success","schema":{"type":"string"}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"500":{"description":"Failure","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Error"}}}}},
"/v1/proxy/resource/mob/getContent":{"get":{...,"responses":{"200":{"description":"Success","schema":{"type":"string"}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"500":{"description":"Failure","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Error"}}}}},
"/v1/proxy/resource/mob/openTask":{"post":{"tags":["v1"],"summary":"Open a task","description":"API to Open a task","operationId":"openTaskUsingPOSTUsingPOST","consumes":["application/json"],"produces":["text/plain"],"parameters":[{"in":"body","name":"cmd","description":"cmd","required":true,"schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/OpenTaskCmd"}}],"responses":{"200":{"description":"Success","schema":{"type":"string"}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"500":{"description":"Failure"}}}},
"/v1/proxy/resource/mob/readActivities":{"get":{...,"responses":{"200":{"description":"Success","schema":{"type":"string"}},"401":{"description":"Unauthorized"},"500":{"description":"Failure","schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Error"}}}}}},
"definitions":{"OpenTaskCmd":{...}}}}}
```

There are two issues with the Json I can't figure out:

1. I have two openTask interfaces, one GET and one POST, but the swagger Json includes only the POST one.
2. For some of the interfaces I get "schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/Error"} for the 500 response, but I don't have this schema and I can't understand why I get it only for some of the services.
   What am I defining wrong?
   Thanks,
   Nir

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to try:

- Upgrade to the latest library version (2.6.0 at the time of this post)
- Remove all the swagger annotations and see what you get. Taken from [the documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/):

  > Philosophically, we want to discourage using (swagger-core) annotations that are not material to the service description at runtime. For e.g. the jackson annotations should always trump or have more weight than `@ApiModelProperty` or for e.g. `@NotNull` or specifying `@RequestParam#required` should always win. Annotations are to to be used only to supplement documentation or override/tweak the resulting spec in cases where its not possible to infer service/schema characteristics.